# Recommendation for new partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I'd like to try Ubuntu one more time. I used to work on Ubuntu KK and MM in my last computer, but when I bought my current laptop I couldn't install it any more because it already had so many partitions by default that I didn't know how to deal with that.

Can anyone please take a look at my partitions and recommend how I can split them to create the new ones to install new Ubuntu 18.04 without eliminating my Windows OS?

[image: partitions in Windows tool]

Comment: It looks like an UEFI system. Be sure to install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode, by booting installer in UEFI mode. Use Windows to shrink NTFS partition & reboot & run chkdsk. Then you can install Ubuntu in unallocated space. With gpt partitioning used with UEFI, your limit of partitions is 128.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would split off 50GB from either C or E, since you have plenty of space left there, then use the new partition to install Ubuntu.